# Get all rows except any models already related

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-5

So I have 2 models in Laravel 5.3.  `Practice` and `Offer`, they have a many to many relationship which is set up and working.  I can attach offers to practices etc.  I want to retrieve all offers that are not already related to the practice.

The logged in user also belongs to the practice with `practice_id`.

In my controller I am passing in `$offer` in the constructor which just relates to all offers.  I've tried using the `reject()` method as below but I'm getting nothing back, and I can't figure it out.

If I use `$this->offer` I get everything.

```
$query = $this->offer->reject(function($offer){
    return $offer->whereHas('practices', function($q) {
        return $q->where('practice_id', Auth::user()->practice_id);
    });
});
```

## Releations

#### User Model

```
public function practice()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Practice::class);
}
```

#### Practice Model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'practice_id');
}

public function offers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class, 'offer_practice')->withTimestamps();
}
```

#### Offer Model

```
public function practices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Practice::class, 'offer_practice')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you show up the relationship b/w `Offer`, `Practice` & `User`?

Comment: You can't use query builder methods on collection!

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi OK, thanks. So how can I create the query I need?

Comment: Do you need those offers, which doesn't have practice associated to the authenticated user. Am I right?

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi.  Correct.  I want all offer that are not already associated to the practice of the current user.

Comment: I've posted the answer below, please have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to work it out like this with the help of @SaumyaRastogi into one small query.

```
$offers = $this->offer->whereHas('practices', function($q) {
    $q->where('practice_id', '<>', auth()->user()->practice->id);
})->orHas('practices', '<', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the use of [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereHas) like this:

This query gives you those offers which aren't related to those practices which have relationship with the authenticated user.

```
$offers = Offer::whereHas('practices', function($q) {
    $q->where('id', '<>', auth()->user()->practice->id);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Whereas, the below query gives you those offers which aren't related to those practices which have relationship with any of the users in the DB.

```
$practice_id_arr = Practice::has('users')->pluck('id')->all();

$offers = Offer::whereHas('practices', function($q) use($practice_id_arr) {
    $q->whereNotIn('id', $practice_id_arr);
});
```

Below query gives you those offers that are not associated with any of the practices:

```
$offers = Offer::doesntHave('practices')->get();
```

Below query gives you those offers that are associated with all practices:

```
$offers = Offer::has('practices')->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @John - I've updated my answer above, please have a look!

Comment: Thanks for this @ SaumyaRastogi however I'm not sure its quite right.  Looking at the query, wouldn't this return only the offers that are associated to other practices?  I need to include offers that are not associated to any as well.

Comment: @John Halsey - Do you want the offers which aren't related to those practices which are not related to any of the users in the DB.?

Comment: @JohnHalsey Not related to any practice?

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi I need all offers from the database that are not already associated to the practice of the current user.  That could be offers that are not associated to any practice, and offers that are associated to other practices.

Comment: @JohnHalsey - I've updated my answer for all the conditions, please have a look.

Comment: Yes I saw that, thank you, but still doesn't seem to do exactly what I needed in one query.  But you definitely pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks for your help.